# Is it possible in c# to do math with file names that contain numbers?

Tags: c#

Is it possible in c# to do math with file names that contain numbers? (i.e. change
file name : "c:\123.img" to "c:\127.img"?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Possible BUT procedure depends on your exact Requirement :)

Comment: I want to decrement or increment the integer values by 5 for multiple file names.

Comment: Is a string parsing statement necessary?

Comment: have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Trying to figure out how I can parse the string, declare/convert the integer value of the string as a integer, use a for each loop to loop through the folder with the files and use the file.move statement to change the names.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

foreach (var f in files)
{
    var info = new FileInfo(f);

    var name = info.Name.Split('.')[0];
    var extension = info.Name.Split('.')[1];

    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(name, out i))
    {
        File.Move(info.FullName, string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}", path, i + 5, extension));
    }
}
```